# How to check if table view cells subtitles are equal to each other iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, uitableview, subtitle

I'm wondering if there is a way to check if a cell's detailTextLabel.text is equal to another cell's detailTextLabel.text.

The reason for this is I would like to set the detailTextLabel.textColor to the same color if the cells texts are equal to each other.

For instance, if there are multiple cells with the same subtitle - lets say I have three cells with a subtitle that say pizza - Id like to set the color for pizza to green.

I fear that adding my code might make things a bit more confusing, as I pull the subtitle from core data based on the user's search text (there's just alot going on as I also persist to core data from a data source). So the subtitles themselves are, in a way, random. My app essentially lets a user search for points of interests based on a category. So if the user searches for pizza, the map view will display any local restaurants that serve pizza. You're then able to save that specific point of interest and the subtitle is set to pizza (or whatever the user searched for). So it's possible to have multiple entries that have the subtitle pizza (if the user saves multiple points of interest based on the 'pizza'.)

Try and forget the logistics of setting the color, I'd really just like to know how I could check if the subtitles are equal to each other in a TableView. I should specify that we are not checking if the actual text is equal to a specific string:

## Not:

```
if(cell.detailTextLabel.text == @"pizza"){
   cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = randomColor;
}
```

## Something like this

```
if(cell.detailTextLabel.text == some other detailTextLabel){
   cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = randomColor;
}
```

## Core Data Example

self.category is my NSManagedObject. In this case I've already been able to persist a randomly generated color to core data. All I really need is the logic to set the color equal to the subtitles that have also been persisted to core data.

```
-(void)configureCell:(CategoryTableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //fetch record
    NSManagedObject *record = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.category = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    float red = [self.category.red floatValue];
    float green = [self.category.green floatValue];
    float blue = [self.category.blue floatValue];

    UIColor *randomRGBColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];
    //update cell
    [cell.textLabel setText:[record valueForKey:@"name"]];
    cell.backgroundColor = randomRGBColor;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is wrong. Why should you compare strings in cells rendered and not before it even started rendering. When you create your `UITableView` you have certain datasource, at least array of `NSString` (titles). 
You can implement a render method in which you loop through the array of titles, find equals and create new array of `NSDictionary` for example, where for key `@"title"` you have your title and for key `@"color"` you have already calculated colour. And in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndex` method you just get the colour from array and assign to `UITableViewCell` instance together with assigning text to `detailTextLabel`.

Comment: absolutely, you can use a Core Data managed object class instead of `NSDictionary` and store your pre-calculated colours there. How do you currently access it, do you use `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Comment: yup! I'm already persisting and fetching for other attributes

Comment: I added an example to my question you might check it out

Comment: @Alex Blair, I see your point, there are some ideas, but I am not sure. The most straightforward way is to loop through your data, create `NSFetchRequest` for your entity, and call `countForFetchRequest` for each, but I think it's not a good idea. Another solution is to delete objects already fetched and finally to sort your data.

Comment: I completely understand where you're coming from. I have some ideas, but I'm in the same boat. Just not sure. I think I may have found a solution...well it's more trickery than a solution. I just ordered my list under sections. So instead of finding equal subtitles, I'm wondering If I can set the background colors of the section labels, and just set the subtitle color equal to the section background color....tricky tricky. Anyways, I appreciate it. I'll upvote and if it's worthy i'd appreciate one as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this with a dictionary in your data layer, where you associate the subtitles with a specific color.

```
var dict = [String: UIColor]
...
if let color = dict[subtitle] {
   //set the color of the cell   
} else {
   let newColor = //some color you haven't used yet
   dict[subtitle] = newColor
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know objective-c would you? I haven't gotten around to swift yet/